# What is the relationship between Storyboards and the Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder

I just started learning XCode, objective-c, iOS, and all that. This is my first foray into app development. I'm not new to development, just iOS development and XCode.

So I'm going through a Udemy course that has me working with storyboards and I have some concern because every professional iOS developer I know uses something called Interface Builder which apparently removes the need for storyboards.

I've only just started, so I still have only a rough idea of what a storyboard even is....it seems to just be a graphical representation of a single page view. I don't know how it relates to this so-called Interface Builder and what their relationship is.

By going through this course learning with storyboards, am I being put on the wrong track? Or is this a useful beginning step before transitioning to the Interface Builder? Will using storyboards help me to work with that later? Am I wasting my time?

Comment: Are you sure you got the nomenclature correct? Your question would make more sense if you mean xib (or nib) instead of storyboard and storyboard instead of interface builder. xibs represent a single page view, storyboards can present the whole flow of views in the app. Interface Builder was an editor for xib files that came bundled with Xcode. Nowadays it's integrated into Xcode (but people still call it Interface Builder for lack of a better name), and it can edit xib and storyboard files.

Comment: "uses something called Interface Builder which apparently removes the need for storyboards." No it doesn't. Interface Builder is just that part of XCode where you do interface related activities. You use IB to create/edit the storyboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...
>   Interface Builder which apparently removes the need for storyboards.
>   ...

Actually, **storyboard** is a concept within Interface Builder.
It's a visual representation of the entire app flow.

I think all you need is a quick-read through the [Apple Interface Builder Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/_index.html).
In basic understanding, IB is a drag-drop area to visually create your views.

**To quote:**

> You create your app’s user interface in Interface Builder. Select a
>   user interface file in the project navigator, and the file’s contents
>   open in Interface Builder in the editor area of the workspace window.
>   A user interface file has the filename extension .storyboard or .xib.

Logical Example: Instead of programmatically coding a `UIButton` and setting it's frame or constraints, you go to the Interface Builder, select a `UIButton` object and place it where you would want it to go. You will also specify what the object name and what method it responds to. (*but this will need the object name and method name to be defined in the respective class's .m or .h file that the view is associated with*)

---

Interface Builder can be either XIB/nib or Storyboard. Latter of which is the more recent (*and recommended*) method provided by Apple.

Using a storyboard, you have one single file, a `.storyboard` file that will represent the entire app flow.
An app can have multiple screens/views and so a storyboard will basically represent multiple `UIViewController`s, each of which will be tied to a particular class.

For example, in this storyboard, you can visually see (*assumptions from here on*) that you have, say, 5 screens in the entire app:

1. Screen 1 begins with maybe a `UINavigationController`
2. Screen 2 is the root view of this `UINavigationController`, say, `LoginVC` <sup>(tied to `LoginVC.m` and `LoginVC.h`)</sup>.

   - A button on `LoginVC` takes you to, say, `SignUpVC` <sup>(tied to `SignUpVC.m` and `SignUpVC.h`)</sup>
   - Another button on `LoginVC` takes you to, say, `ProfileVC` <sup>(tied to `ProfileVC.m` and `ProfileVC.h`)</sup>
3. Screen 3 is `SignUpVC`

   - A button takes you back to `LoginVC`
4. Screen 4 is `ProfileVC`

   - A button takes you to `SettingsVC` <sup>(tied to `SettingsVC.m` and `SettingsVC.h`)</sup>
   - A button logs you out and takes you back to `LoginVC`
5. Screen 5 is `SettingsVC`

---

Q.

> By going through this course learning with storyboards, am I being put on the wrong track?

A.
No, absolutely not. You're going in the right direction.
However, i think knowing the former XIB/nib method is worth your time as well.
Plus, programmatically creating `UIView`s is highly recommended.

---

Q.

> ...is this a useful beginning step before transitioning to the Interface Builder?

A.
It's already getting you acquainted with the Interface Builder so there won't really be much "transitioning" required.

---

Q.

> Will using storyboards help me to work with that later? Am I wasting my time?

A.
Yes, unless you work in a team under version control, in which case, XIB still looks good.

---

### So what's XIB?

It's still within the Interface Builder scope...
Break a storyboard into it's individual views and you have multiple files (*`.xib` files*) that represent a `UIView` or `UIViewController` for a single class. (*hence helps when you work in a team under version control*)

So now... instead of having one `.storyboard`, you will have multiple `.xib` files that will be associated to all those classes that (*you deem*) needed a visual representation.

---

Links:

- [Storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Storyboard.html)
- [XIB](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html)

Answer (score 3):

The `Interface Builder` refers to the part of Xcode that lets you view and edit Storyboards and .xib files (it automatically opens when you click on such a file).

A .xib (or 'nib') file is a representation of a single logical view in you application (on iOS, typically a `UIViewController` with a number of views, such as a `UIScrollView` and a `UINavigationBar`).

A storyboard is a collection of such views, and can be used to build transitions from views to other views, among other things.

I recommend reading [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Storyboard.html) on storyboards to get an idea of what they can do for you.

Comment: I'd quibble about the "single view" part of the answer.  It could be any number of views, usually managed by the same view controller (…but not guaranteed).

Comment: True, by 'single view' I did not mean a single `UIView`/`NSView` instance, but a 'logical view' - I'll edit the answer to make that clear.

Answer (score -1):

Storyboard :
Has a nice UI designer , WYSIWYG , drag, resize design editor, that generates code and sync with manual code changes.

SwiftUI:
Code is the single source of truth. No Designer. Lots of hard coding